# Ubuntu upstart and issue with dns resolution not ready during reboot

Tags: upstart

I created in /etc/init a monit.conf file that is pretty standard.  During reboot, however, when monit tries to start, it checks dns resolution for things in its configuration file (monitrc) but fails.  I had to add a pre-start stanza to get it to loop and keep trying to resolve a dns name before it goes and tries to start monit. It just seems kind of clunky though.  I am guessing this is related to network stuff not starting until a script in /etc/init.d for networking runs and that my monit stuff starts before that unless I use this loop check. I tried:

start on (net-device-up IFACE=eth0 and runlevel [2345]), thinking that this would make sure that the interface was up and that we were in a runlevel where networking should at least be running, but that did not help.  Is there some other key word I can put in start on that checks if resolution is available?  Please note my server is not running dns server.

Answer (score 1):

You might try starting when networking is up and running.

```
start on started networking
```

However your job is depending on external condition (DNS resolution) therefore loop you created might be inevitable.

You should also re-check your monit configuration: [The upstart script](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Upstart) provided on Monit web site looks straight forward. No mention of problems you are facing.

Case you haven't done it already check the content of /var/log/upstart/monit.log and [debug](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging) your script. Knowing exactly why your script is failing on reboot could be helpful.